# Android Java recycle View scrolling: will it redownload images?

Tags: java, android, caching, picasso

I am using picasso in my recycler view. I am wondering about the caching: When I scroll down the images disappear and when I scroll up again, they show again. But its displaying the progress bar for downloading and it takes like a second to show it.

my code

```
                Picasso.get().load(profileUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image).fit().into(postViewHolder.profileImg);
```

I want to avoid downloading the same images multiple times. Or is it just the caching that takes some time to display the already cached image again?

Answer (score 0):

Picasso should cache images automatically. You can can check if it's cached by using the `setIndicatorsEnabled` method on the Picasso singleton instance.

- Red: Downloading over the network.
- Blue: Image was cached on disc.
- Green: Image was cached in memory.

Comment: Thanks. However, it always shows the red flag. Even if it was loaded previously

Comment: Can you confirm the following behaviour:


First run: image loads from NETWORK (red flag)
- Background and re-open the app: image loads from MEMORY (green)
- Kill the app and re-open: image loads from DISK (blue)

Comment: You could also call:
`Log.d("Picasso Stats", Picasso.get().getSnapshot().toString())`
And paste the output here.

Comment: Well it shows the green dot on a few of the images after reloading them. When I kill the app, it shows the red ones again. I Have a similar feed to instagram etc so that's fine. I am only concerned about when scrolling a bit up and down it is always showning that it is re downloading

Comment: StatsSnapshot{maxSize=76695844, size=0, cacheHits=0, cacheMisses=0, downloadCount=0, totalDownloadSize=0, averageDownloadSize=0, totalOriginalBitmapSize=0, totalTransformedBitmapSize=0, averageOriginalBitmapSize=0, averageTransformedBitmapSize=0, originalBitmapCount=0, transformedBitmapCount=0, timeStamp=1611590206678}

Comment: Picasso Stats: StatsSnapshot{maxSize=76695844, size=5848952, cacheHits=2, cacheMisses=3, downloadCount=3, totalDownloadSize=74781, averageDownloadSize=24927, totalOriginalBitmapSize=3338496, totalTransformedBitmapSize=5848952, averageOriginalBitmapSize=1112832, averageTransformedBitmapSize=1949650, originalBitmapCount=3, transformedBitmapCount=3, timeStamp=1611590321701}

Comment: First load, then when I refresh the same images. Looks fine to me, but the behavior is not the best as when you scroll its loading the image which takes some time. Hm

Comment: I believe for disc caching, Picasso just relies on the caching of whatever HTTP client it's using for downloading, so you may want to check the headers in the response when fetching the image to see if the caching behaviour is correct.

Alternatively you could just maintain your own cache of images in memory. In the adapter, I sometimes keep a map of bitmaps and item id's and try to load it first from here in the `onBindViewHolder` method.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso by default cache image .  if you dont want cache using this code

```
Picasso.with(context).load(uri).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).memoryPolicy(MemoryPlicy.NO_CACHE).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageView);
```